# why can't I acces symfony after installation ? Here's the message I get : "-bash: symfony: command not found"

Tags: symfony

I'm discovering `symfony` and on a way to develop a web app. I just installed it (a couple of days now) but yet I can't have access to it through my `terminal`. It shows `command not found` is the principal message I get when I try. checked php and composer, they are all ok. But still don't have access to `symfony`.

Tried using this code

```
"hardpro$ mv /usr/hardpro/bin/composer.phar /usr/hardpro/bin/composer" to change the directory but yet, nothing.

ESOservices:~ hardpro$ documents/symfony
-bash: documents/symfony: No such file or directory

ESOservices:~ hardpro$ documents/symfony new
-bash: documents/symfony: No such file or directory

ESOservices:~ hardpro$ cd esoServices
-bash: cd: esoServices: No such file or directory

ESOservices:~ hardpro$ cd symfony
-bash: cd: symfony: No such file or directory

ESOservices:~ hardpro$ symfony new --full my_project
-bash: symfony: command not found

ESOservices:~ hardpro$ mv /usr/local/bin/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
mv: rename /usr/local/bin/composer.phar to /usr/local/bin/composer: No such file or directory

ESOservices:~ hardpro$ mv /usr/hardpro/bin/composer.phar /usr/hardpro/bin/composer
mv: rename /usr/hardpro/bin/composer.phar to /usr/hardpro/bin/composer: No such file or directory
```

Comment: which installation tutorial did you follow?

Comment: The one on the symfony website "https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#creating-symfony-applications"

Comment: When you install symfony you are uitstalling a bunch of directories and files but not a symfony executable file. Just find your project directory and locate the index.php in the public directory. Try to open that file in your browser.

Comment: @FrankB The question is about a Symfony executable file and not a Symfony project.  The executable is alternative way to create projects, it can also act as a web server and provides an interface to Symfony Cloud.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to define the PATH. Run this command before you want to run the `symfony` command.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.symfony/bin:$PATH"
```

Then you should be able to run a command like `symfony server:start`, but you would need to run the export every time you reopen your terminal.
To solve it permanently, you would need to add this command to your bash profile.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have an error with your installation, you should install it again.

To install symfony : https://symfony.com/download

To install composer : https://getcomposer.org/download

To use it globally : https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally

You have to run the command `mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer` in the same folder where you run the install composer commands.

Comment: Just did that. Thank you. But now, how do I have access to the "symfony" command ? It doesn't work